# foreach td loop values

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

I have the following within my foreach....this works but there are 2 sets of values per $value and it only shows the first

```
<?php
$info = simplexml_load_file("https://api.website.co.za/ACCESS_GetAccountSessions?"); 
echo "<ul info>";

foreach ($info->sessions as $sessions): 
$count = $sessions->{'session-count'};
$ip = $sessions->session->{'ip-address'};
$nas = $sessions->session->{'nas-ip-address'};
$port = $sessions->session->{'nas-port'};
$phone = 'N/A';

            ?>


<?php
                    echo '<tr>',

              '<td class="blockcontentwhite sessionicon">',
              '<td class="blockcontentwhite center">' . ("$ip") . '</td>',
              '<td class="blockcontentwhite center">' . ("$nas") . '</td>',
              '<td class="blockcontentwhite center">' . ("$port") . '</td>',
              '<td class="blockcontentwhite center">' . ("$phone") . '</td>',

                    '</tr>';
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
```

so basically within a table on 1st row its showing the $ip , $nas, $port and $phone BUT it is not showing the second values on the 2nd row , any ideas?

Thanks Guys

Comment: Can you show us the complete code so we can see how you are running the loop?

Comment: make sure array on which you are performing loop has second element inside of it..

Comment: Can you show whole foreach loop ?

Comment: Hi , edited my question with full loop code

Comment: @Lefty, are you sure there are more rows?

Comment: sorry  just added all :)

Comment: @Lefty, what does `print_r($info)` prints on the screen?

Comment: @Jueecy , it prints all the values , including the second values that should be on second row

Comment: @Lefty, may I see the output (you should edit your question including the output of `print_r`).

Comment: @Lefty could you modify `print_r($info)` to `echo '<pre>'; print_r($info); echo '</pre>';` and **edit** your question post **above** to include the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access an object as an array. `$info->sessions` is of type `SimpleXMLElement Object` which *contains* (as a property) the array you want to use in the foreach.

Change your foreach ( `foreach ($info->sessions as $sessions):` ) to `foreach ($info->sessions->session as $sessions):` and:

```
$count = $sessions->{'session-count'};
$ip = $sessions->session->{'ip-address'};
$nas = $sessions->session->{'nas-ip-address'};
$port = $sessions->session->{'nas-port'};
$phone = 'N/A';
```

to:

```
$count = $info->sessions->{'session-count'};
$ip = $sessions->{'ip-address'};
$nas = $sessions->{'nas-ip-address'};
$port = $sessions->{'nas-port'};
$phone = 'N/A';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Jueecy is correct regarding the question you asked about.

But I noticed something that looks like it might be a problem besides that. It looks like the code will generate multiple tables, but I think you just want multiple rows in the same table.

I would suggest moving your foreach down to where you are generating the rows:

```
<?php
$info = simplexml_load_file("https://api.website.co.za/ACCESS_GetAccountSessions?"); 
echo "<ul info>";
?>

<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ctl00$contentDefault$contentControlPanel$hdnIsSecure"     id="ctl00_ctl00_contentDefault_contentControlPanel_hdnIsSecure" value="false" />
<table id="active_sessions_table" class="blocktable centered" cellpadding="0"   cellspacing="0">
<tr class="blockheader">
<td id="active_sessions_title" class="left" colspan="2">
      <label  class="floatleft">Current connections</label></td>
</tr>
<tr id="trconnections">
<td class="blockcellnopadding" colspan="2">
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%"  style="border-bottom:solid 1px  #bfbfbf;">
        <tr>
            <td class="columntitle center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="columntitle center">IP Address</td>
            <td class="columntitle center">NAS IP Address</td>
            <td class="columntitle center">Line Port</td>
            <td class="columntitle center">Telephone Number</td>
        </tr>
<?php
        foreach ($info->sessions->session as $session) {
            $ip = $session->{'ip-address'};
            $nas = $session->{'nas-ip-address'};
            $port = $session->{'nas-port'};
            $phone = 'N/A';

            echo '<tr>',
          '<td class="blockcontentwhite sessionicon">',
          '<td class="blockcontentwhite center">' . ("$ip") . '</td>',
          '<td class="blockcontentwhite center">' . ("$nas") . '</td>',
          '<td class="blockcontentwhite center">' . ("$port") . '</td>',
          '<td class="blockcontentwhite center">' . ("$phone") . '</td>',

          '</tr>';
       };
?>
```